# WebView not even RECOGNIZING download request - Android

Tags: java, android, webview, download

So first off I'm using Advanced Webview https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

So I can finally accept downloads in webview, but the download link on my website is not even being recognized by the following code:

```
public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Note: My download button is almost exactly identical to the one found on this website: https://www.editpad.org/
Both download text files and both don't work.

---

Code works at: https://unsplash.com/search/photos/animals

Code does NOT work at: https://www.editpad.org/

---

On the browser it downloads fine, but in app it doesn't.
What do I do so that the download request is recognized.

Comment: Did you add permissions?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>